# Send XMLRPC Request using Java

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I am trying to send an XMLRPC Request via Java and is unsuccessful. Here's the structure of XMLRPC Request that I need to send with method name create.account:

```
<createaccount>
<functioncode>bank_account</functioncode> <cardnumber>55553263654898</cardnumber>
<transaction_id>12345678</transaction_id>
<transactiondatetime>2012-01-08 14:12:22</transactiondatetime>
</createaccount>
```

As per client, I should be expecting the following XMLRPC Response:

```
<createaccount>
<code>200</code>
<message>SUCCESS</message>
<functioncode>bank_account</functioncode> 
<cardnumber>55553263654898</cardnumber>
<transaction_id>12345678</transaction_id>
<transactiondatetime>2012-01-08 14:12:22</transactiondatetime>
</createaccount>
```

I have made the following snippet in java but I'm getting an error: 'Failed to create input stream: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL'

Here's the snippet:

```
    XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();

        config.setServerURL(new URL(server_url));
        XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
        config.setBasicUserName(pUser);
        config.setBasicPassword(pPassword);
        client.setConfig(config);

        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("functioncode", "bank_account");
        m.put("cardnumber", "55553263654898");
        m.put("transaction_id", "12345678");
        m.put("transactiondatetime", "2012-01-08 14:12:22");

        Object[] params = new Object[]{m};
        String result = (String)client.execute("bank.account", params);
        System.out.println("Results:" + result);
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Is there anyone there that can help?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using XML-RPC library, for example Redston XML-RPC. More info and tutorial can be found [here](http://xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/).